# How to replace array value with another array value using php?

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays as follows:

```
$arr = array('one.jpg', 'two.jpg', 'three.jpg');
$arr1 = array('', 'five.jpg', '');
```

Now I want to make these two arrays to one array with following value:

```
$newArray = array('one.jpg', 'five.jpg', 'three.jpg');
```

How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: What's the exact logic supposed to be…? Non-falsey values from the second array replace the value at the same index in the first array?

Comment: you have to execute loop for second array and update the second array while getting null value in it

Comment: `$newArray = [$arr[0], $arr1[1], $arr[2]];`

Comment: @GordonM Eye cee wat u did thar…

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty values.

Use [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to replace the values from the first array with the remaining values of the 2nd array.

```
$arr1=array_filter($arr1);
var_dump(array_replace($arr,$arr1));
```

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* you want to overwrite entries in the first array only with *truthy* values from the second:

```
$newArray = array_map(function ($a, $b) { return $b ?: $a; }, $arr, $arr1);
```

Comment: This operator threw me off, again learn something today, thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through array and check value for second array :

```
$arr = array('one.jpg', 'two.jpg', 'three.jpg');
$arr1 = array('', 'five.jpg', '');
$newArray =array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($arr1[$key]) && $arr1[$key] != "")
        $newArray[$key] = $arr1[$key];
    else
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using a for loop, not sure whether there is a more elegant one:

```
$arr = array('one.jpg', 'two.jpg', 'three.jpg');
$arr1 = array('', 'five.jpg', '');

$newArray = array();
$size = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
    if(!empty($arr1[$i])){
       $newArray[$i] = $arr1[$i];
    } else {
       $newArray[$i] = $arr[$i];
    }
 }
```